# Are there intermodal tramp freight carriers?

Tags: international-trade, nonexpert

I'm working on a fictional system where shippers -- companies with bulk goods to ship -- post contracts stating an origin, destination, and number of cargo containers.

Carriers -- whether by air, land or sea -- compete for the contracts, but conversely have to partner with other carriers to complete the contract. (For instance, a farm may hire a truck fleet to take its produce to a rail yard, where a train takes it to a container ship.)

These are all "tramp" carriers -- they have no set routes or schedules. And they are all independent of each other.

My question is -- how much of this scenario occurs in real life?  Are there exchanges where shippers shop for carriers?  Are there really tramp rail and air freighters?